# Capture intent destination

Tags: android

I have an Android app with an option to share the app:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                activity.getResources().getString(R.string.share_checkout)
                +": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.mountainreacher.nocropforwhatsapp");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

For analysis purposes I would like to know what app is the user choosing to share the content:

[image]

Is that posible?

Answer (score 3):

On Android 5.1 and higher, you can [use `EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER) to find out what choice the user made in the chooser.

Prior to that, the only way to know what the user chooses is to skip the system chooser and implement your own, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.